# What is the wrong here on associaction cake php

Tags: cakephp, associations

I am working on cake php and I have an association with users and `user_details` table, When I sign up then its working fine. Its post data on both the tables but when I redirect to profile page then it throws an error of `userDetail` array. When I printed that info array I got only one array instead of two arrays one is User and another one is `UserDetail`. Its working fine on my local machine but not working on server, But when I used `recursive=>1` than its works. Please let me know what wrong here.

**Query**

```
$userInfo = $this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$userId)));
```

when I pass recursive than it works

```
$userInfo = $this->User->find('first',array('recursive'=>1,'conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$userId)));
```

Thanks
Shiv

Answer (score 1):

Please use `Containable` behavior. It's more intuitive and clean then `recursive` variable. You can do this adding in your `AppModel` (or specific models if you don't want this behavior in all of them):

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Then, in your find:

```
$userInfo = $this->User->find('first',array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'User.id'=> $userId
    ),
    'contain' => array('UserDetail')
));
```

If you have declared your association, you will retrieve your `User` along any `UserDetail` for that `User`

Answer (score 0):

If you always want UserDetail to be fetched when you do a find on User, add the $recursive property to your User model:

```
public $recursive = 1;
```

However, the above is not recommended as usually, `$recursive` should be set to -1 in your AppModel. This is because `Model::find()` should normally only fetch data from a single model and not ALL related models. E.g. if your User model is related to say UserDetail and UserRole model, data from all of them will be fetched if $recursive is not equal to -1. This slows down your app.

When you do require related model data like in your question, use the [containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) like this:

```
$userInfo = $this->User->find('first', array(
  'conditions' => array('User.id'=>$userId),
  'contain' => array('UserDetail')
));
```